# Updating the view of a UICollectionView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am working on a [Swift iOS Calendar Library](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar) which uses a UICollectionView to display dates.

Apple recently has an upgrade to UICollectionView which pre-fetches cells. With it, the library scrolls smoothly, but there is a problem it has caused.

Question: How do I update CellView that is both:

1. **Not** currently visible on the screen
2. Has already been pre-fetched

?

Before, I could update the view of the cell in the `cellForItem` function. But, if the cell has already been pre-fetched, that function does not seem to be called when the cells comes into view.

Comment: `willdisplaycell` then ??

Comment: reloading UICollectionView works?

Comment: ok. I'm feeling a bit silly for something so simple. I reloaded the indexPath. If you put up an answer here i'll accept it